# Annualize monthly Returns

Tags: r, return

I am trying to convert the following DT test1 from monthly returns to annualised yearly returns. I am trying to group them by "Id" and "hcjun" (accounting period from jul to jun).

```
 hcjun       ym     Id RET.USD
 1:  1997 Jul 1997 142521  -11.14
 2:  1997 Aug 1997 142521    6.79
 3:  1997 Sep 1997 142521    3.32
 4:  1997 Oct 1997 142521    2.04
 5:  1997 Nov 1997 142521   -0.89
 6:  1997 Dec 1997 142521    1.84
 7:  1997 Jan 1998 142521    4.74
 8:  1997 Feb 1998 142521   -5.05
 9:  1997 Mar 1998 142521    3.60
10:  1997 Apr 1998 142521    3.42
11:  1997 May 1998 142521   40.10
12:  1997 Jun 1998 142521   21.64
13:  1997 Jul 1997 142802   10.46
14:  1997 Aug 1997 142802   -6.58
15:  1997 Sep 1997 142802   12.29
16:  1997 Oct 1997 142802   -6.36
17:  1997 Nov 1997 142802    0.02
18:  1997 Dec 1997 142802    3.60
19:  1997 Jan 1998 142802    5.14
20:  1997 Feb 1998 142802    4.96
21:  1997 Mar 1998 142802   21.70
22:  1997 Apr 1998 142802    4.95
23:  1997 May 1998 142802    5.46
24:  1997 Jun 1998 142802   -8.36
    hcjun       ym     Id RET.USD
```

I have tried this in a really basic form but couldn't get it to work:

```
test1 %>%
  group_by(hcjun, Id) %>%
  summarize(annual_return = prod(1 + RET.USD/100) - 1)
```

Ideally, the output will be in this case two rows for each ID with the annualised return in 1997.

This is the data:

```
structure(list(hcjun = c(1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L
), ym = structure(c(1997.5, 1997.58333333333, 1997.66666666667, 
1997.75, 1997.83333333333, 1997.91666666667, 1998, 1998.08333333333, 
1998.16666666667, 1998.25, 1998.33333333333, 1998.41666666667, 
1997.5, 1997.58333333333, 1997.66666666667, 1997.75, 1997.83333333333, 
1997.91666666667, 1998, 1998.08333333333, 1998.16666666667, 1998.25, 
1998.33333333333, 1998.41666666667), class = "yearmon"), Id = c("142521", 
"142521", "142521", "142521", "142521", "142521", "142521", "142521", 
"142521", "142521", "142521", "142521", "142802", "142802", "142802", 
"142802", "142802", "142802", "142802", "142802", "142802", "142802", 
"142802", "142802"), RET.USD = c(-11.14, 6.79, 3.32, 2.04, -0.89, 
1.84, 4.74, -5.05, 3.6, 3.42, 40.1, 21.64, 10.46, -6.58, 12.29, 
-6.36, 0.02, 3.6, 5.14, 4.96, 21.7, 4.95, 5.46, -8.36)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fa6c8813ce0>, sorted = "hcjun")
```

I would highly appreciate it, if somebody could help me!

Best, Fred

Comment: Please add an example of what you want the output to look like and set up your question as a minimal example, e.g. with an example data.frame that can be reproduced.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! Is it clear now?

Comment: You haven't really explained why you are trying to group them. RIght now your code is basically identifying unique conjunctions of hcjun and id then within each of those groups it is then dividing each row by 100, adding 1 to that, multipling them all by each other, then subtracting 1.  Doesn't seem to be what you want but then again it's not clear why you are grouping anything. Seems like you are actually wanting to annualize monthly then aggregate in some way, but not clear.

Comment: Well, I want to show the annualised return by Id. I don't really have a starting point, but the calculation within my "attempt" would yield for the annualised return.

Comment: @FreddyMüller Why "output will be in this case two rows for each ID" when you have a single year in hcjun column?